# Loop fails during first attempt

Tags: c++

I am completing a lab assignment where the user is prompted for the type if fish they wish to order and to enter the price per pound. The user needs to be prompted for the type of fish and the price two times before the report prints.

The problem is that the program ends before the first instance of the loop has completed. (The way the code is written the titles on the report will print twice, but that was in the instructions.)

The code is below and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        float price;
    string fishType;
    int counter = 0;

    // Change the console's background color.
    system ("color F0");

    while (counter < 3){

    // Collect input from the user.
    cout << "Enter the type of seafood: ";
    cin >> fishType; // <------ FAILS AT THIS POINT. I GET THE PROMPT AND AT THE                                  "ENTER" IT DISPLAYS THE REPORT

    cout << "Enter the price per pound using dollars and cents: ";
    cin >> price;

    counter++;
    }

    // Display the report.
    cout << "          SEAFOOD REPORT\n\n";
    cout << "TYPE OF               PRICE PER" << endl;
    cout << "SEAFOOD                   POUND" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint<< left << setw(25) 
        << fishType << "$" << setw(5) << right << price << endl;

    cout << "\n\n";
    system ("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell exactly where it is ending?  Are you getting the prompts before it ends?

Comment: TIme to run the debugger and see which line is failing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new line character will not have been consumed by the read, using [`std::istream::operator>>(float)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt), of the `price`:

```
cin >> price; // this will not consume the new line character.
```

The presence of the new line character during the next read, using [`operator>>(std::istream, std::string)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)), into `fishType`:

```
cin >> fishType; // Reads a blank line, effectively.
```

and then the user input that was intended to be the next `fishType` will be read (and fail to be) by the `price` as it will not be a valid `float` value.

To correct, [`ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) until the next new line character after the read of the `price`. Something like:

```
cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
// or: cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Always check the status of input operation to determine if they were successful or not. This is easily achieved:

```
if (cin >> price)
{
    // success.
}
```

If the `fishType` can contain spaces then using `operator>>(std::istream, std::string)` is not appropriate as it will stop reading at the first whitespace. Use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead:

```
if (std::getline(cin, fishType))
{
}
```

---

When the user enters input a new line character will be written to `stdin`, i.e `cin`:

```
cod\n
1.9\n
salmon\n
2.7\n
```

On first iteration of the loop:

```
cin >> fishType; // fishType == "cod" as operator>> std::string
                 // will read until first whitespace.
```

and `cin` now contains:

```
\n
1.9\n
salmon\n
2.7\n
```

then:

```
cin >> price; // This skips leading whitespace and price = 1.9
```

and `cin` now contains:

```
\n
salmon\n
2.7\n
```

then:

```
cin >> fishType; // Reads upto the first whitespace
                 // i.e reads nothin and cin is unchanged.
cin >> price;    // skips the whitespace and fails because
                 // "salmon" is not a valid float.
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean ?

Comment: price is an int and won't grab the newline.  need to grab that as a seperate string read I believe.

Comment: I partially figured it out, when inputting the fish type as Sea Bass, it is reading the Bass as the price. How do I pull in the whole line as the name of the fish?

Comment: @KevinSchultz, updated answer with explanation of what is happening. Hope it is clearer to you now.